# Give me specificity, or give me breadth!

Tags: discussion, standards, asking-questions

I limited [my question regarding "male enhancement" techniques](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/do-male-enhancement-products-actually-work) to just those of the "magic pill" variety not because I wasn't interested in how well the other techniques worked, but because I thought that such a question would be a little too broad to be appropriate for this site.  Another question [was closed for being overly broad](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/i-am-disappointed-by-the-hostility-of-this-community), but it was far more wide ranging than mine.

I feel that my question, expanded to include all possible techniques, would still be acceptable.  It will continue to focus on a defined set of testable end results, while allowing for several more techniques to be analyzed.

Would my question be acceptable if its scope was expanded in this manner, or would it be better to instead ask several questions focusing on each method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your question has one huge problem you should address first:

It has a VERY IMPORTANT caveat at the bottom that looks like it was edited in later. This is .. uh, bad. I edited the title to move that to the top where it belonged.

Beyond that, I think scoping it to "non-FDA approved magic pills" is the correct strategy. It is possible for questions occasionally to make the mistake of being too narrow, but it's far, *far* more common to make the mistake of being *too broad*.

So I'd tend to err on the side of being specific and narrow where possible. I support the question as-is with my title edit.

Answer (score 2):

I like the smaller scope because it is easier to write about than a broader one would have been. I only have so much time and there's a lot of related information out there! Other techniques have their own issues worth discussing and if I see a question related to them, I would likely write as much, if not more, than I did in response to your question as it is now. That's just my opinion, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd support adding a similar question with the different scope, since you said in the comments you were originally interested in the whole picture. I think that both my off-topic answer (would it be on-topic) and SophieMonster's on-topic one is to long anyways.

If you create another similar question, I would move my answer there. I'm assuming no-one would object to that.